Slavery and freedom
From moral justification view, this verse about slavery is concerning to me, not really about the slavery, it's about the wife and children of a few slave that are left behind when he's freed. It states this in the verse

If his master gave him a wife while he was a slave and they had sons
or daughters, then only the man will be free in the seventh year, but
his wife and children will still belong to his master. [ ‭Exodus 21:4
NLT‬]

My questions are:
Would the kids continue as slaves for the master?
When the wife needs her conjugal rights, what should happen?
Please kindly support your answers with scriptural references.

The same question was posted yesterday as exodus - Slavery and freedom - Christianity Stack Exchange.

+1 Note that the context of Exodus 21 concerns Hebrew slaves specifically. "1 Now these are the rules that you shall set before them. 2 When you buy a Hebrew slave . . . " This is completely different than old world chattel slavery and new world plantation slavery.  It was primarily a debt repayment institution limited to a maximum of six years. It was more like what we think of indentured servitude. Reading the passage carefully, one can see that children would remain with the mother until the debt was paid or six years had elapsed. Presumably a dowry was paid by the master.

@Dieter I have seen no place where it claimed the woman and her kids will be free after full repayment of their debts. Would you mind to clarify?

@ken4ward, Torah is meant to be like fenceposts along a fence. The space between the posts is to be logically inferred. In new situations, it is to be extrapolated. This is very much like modern case law. In Deuteronomy 15, there's additional information, including the labor value of a slave was half that of a hired laborer, but had to be fed, housed, clothed, and rewarded at the end for the purpose of eliminating poverty and homelessness in Israel. The question to ask yourself (not for discussion here) is whether you'd rather see homeless people sleeping and begging in the streets.

The institution of slavery in ancient Israel was significantly different from modern conceptions of slavery. The Biblical laws concerning slavery were intended to regulate and mitigate its harsh realities rather than endorse or condone it.
1. The kids may indeed remain:

4 If his master has given him a wife, and she has borne him sons or
daughters, the wife and her children shall be her master’s, and he
shall go out by himself.

However, if they married in captivity it's likely that the kids would remain too young to provide much help.
Note this though: No matter what, all Hebrew debt slaves were to be freed every seven years. No Hebrew owned another; just their labor, and that for a limited time.
Scenario 1: The Man Was Unmarried

---> Man's Debt Paid Off
---> Man is Free to Go

Scenario 2: The Man Was Married and Brought His Wife (Wife has no Debt)

---> Man's Debt Paid Off
---> Man and Wife Both Free to Go

Scenario 3: The Man Married A Woman in Debt While in Debt

---> Man's Debt Paid Off

---> Man Is Free to Go

---> Wife's Debt Not Paid Off

---> Wife and Children Remain with Master


In case of the third scenario the husband had a few options:
Options for the Husband's Freed Slavery Status:

Wait for Wife's Debt to Be Paid

Scripture: Exodus 21:4
Outcome: Once the wife finishes working off her debt, she and the children can join the husband.


Pay Off Wife's Debt

Scripture: None directly stated
Outcome: The husband may use any excess resources to pay off his wife's debt, allowing her to join him sooner.


Continue Employment

Scripture: Exodus 21:5-6
Outcome: If the situation is favorable, the husband may choose to remain in the employment of the master, ensuring continued stability and benefits for the family.




2. The Bible does not specifically address this scenario in the context of the Hebrew law concerning slavery.

Conjugal rights refer to the mutual rights and privileges between two
individuals arising from the state of being married. These rights
include mutual rights of companionship, support, comfort, sexual
relations, affection, joint property rights and the like.

All that it says on this is:

10 If he takes another wife, he shall not diminish her food, her
clothing, and her marriage rights.


"No matter what, all debt slaves were to be freed every seven years. Nobody owned anybody else; just their labor, and that for a limited time"
This is completely misstating biblical slavery. Only Israelite slaves were freed after 6/7 years of slavery. Non-Israelites who were taken or purchased as slaves were chattel slaves and able to be inherited, and the slaves children were inherited as well. See Leviticus 25:44 onwards. So yes, people owned other people

You're right. When I stated "all debt slaves were to be freed every seven years", I meant it to accurately reflect the biblical regulation concerning Hebrew debt slaves as outlined in Exodus 21:2-6 and Deuteronomy 15:12-18. I will add the word Hebrew to be clear!

@Jason_ Scenario 2 & 3 does not exist regarding this. It seems like an opportunity for the master to reproduce more slaves for himself. There was no direct mention of either giving him a Jewish or non-jewish wife, as long as the master contracted the marriage, he'll only use the supposed Jewish man to reproduce slaves for himself which are permanent perpetual slaves. In this case, it'll be a matter of how many the man can reproduce before his 7 year tenure elapses. This makes him disposable, and the children continue from where their father stopped. Do you agree with this?

According to traditional Jewish sources (Rashi, Ramban), this verse refers to a non-Jewish slave woman who was mated to a Jewish slave man during his up-to-6 years of slavery. This slave woman, despite being mated (think more like concubine than regular marriage) to the Jewish man, was not freed when he was freed. She, and any children, would continue to be slaves.
The previous refers to a Jewish man as a slave who was married prior to becoming a slave. In that situation, his wife leaves with him.
Note that a Jewish man, slave or not, would not normally be permitted to have relations with a non-Jewish woman, whether a slave or not. This was a special exception.
The following two verses provide a procedure whereby the Jewish slave man could choose to remain as a slave in order to stay with the non-Jewish slave woman and their children. This was discouraged, but it was permitted.
In any case, he would go free at the next Jubilee year, but depending on timing that could be very quickly or decades away.

Hey! Welcome to the Biblical H.SE. We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out what we are looking for in answers and the FAQs. This site can be tricky at first. In short, we look for answers that show effort, research, and references. Maybe consider an edit to add citations and reliable sources to your answer.

+1 Thank you for your insightful comment!
